# Why is my export sink from Stackdriver only loading the latest audit logs into BigQuery and no historical?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-bigquery

I created an export sink in Stackdriver to load audit logs into BigQuery. I want to be able to see audit logs from the past 3 months. However, when I queried the tables in BigQuery, I am only seeing logs from today and no earlier.

I applied the following filters to my export sink. I also tried removing the timestamp filter but still only seeing logs from today and no prior.

resource.type="bigquery_dataset"
timestamp > "2019-05-01T23:59:09.739Z"

Comment: When did you add the export (sink) from Stackdriver to BQ?  Only records originated AFTER the creation of the export definition are written to BQ .. not ones from earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Exports only work for new entries.

Per the documentation -- 
"exporting happens for new log entries only, you cannot export log entries that Logging received before your sink was created."

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/#how_sinks_work

Comment: It should be possible to perform a "dump" of Stackdriver log entries matching a given filter to storage (local file system or GCS) and then import that dumped data into BQ to "augment" what is then written automatically by the newly defined export rule.

Comment: Ah that answers it. I just added the sink export today. Is there a way to retrieve historical logs from Stackdriver then?